# What's the best way to use Node Sass on Windows in 2022? Error: 'Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass

I am having issues installing SASS with create react app. Is there any windows specific practice?

I tried:

`npm install --save-dev node-sass`

I also uninstalled then re-installed.

Here are the error messages:

````
npm ERR! invalid: node-sass@6.0.0 /Users/leo/dev/Python/project/frontend/node_modules/node-sass

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/leo/.npm/_logs/2021-05-10T09_05_18_799Z-debug.log

React Complie Log:
Failed to compile.
./src/styles/_global.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/styles/_global.scss)
Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0.```
````

Comment: [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) is deprecated, use [`sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe that got me on the path to figuring out the issue. I searched through stack a bunch but wasn't seeing that the node-sass had been deprecated. I think the issue is that people are still posting issues about node sass and giving work around solutions when they should just be installing sass and not node sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node Sass is deprecated.
You can try uninstalling it by using this command:

`npm uninstall node-sass`  and trying:

`npm install --save-dev sass`

this worked for me when I was having issues installing sass on a project using create react app

https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated

Comment: Would very much appreciate an upvote :) Hope this answer helps :)